# ChannelFactory resolving an address for a different tenant

Tags: wcf, azure-aks

We have a multi tenant architecture in the cloud.I have noticed a strange behavior where often App1 of tenant 1 calls App2 of tenant 2.  This is not a frequent behavior and happens few times a day.  Below is a generic code snippet that calls App2 from App1. Logging of addresses from App1 shows the correct values. But logging values at App2 shows the request originated from a different tenant. Could it be possible that ChannelFactory caches the values or something else that I am missing.

> public SvcProxyBase(string endPointName)
> {
> EndpointAddress EA = new EndpointAddress(GetBaseAddress(endPointName));
> _endPointName = endPointName;
> _eA = EA;
> ClientBase.CacheSetting = CacheSetting.AlwaysOn;
>
> _factory = new ChannelFactory(endPointName, EA);
> System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("WCF ENDPOINT: " + _factory.Endpoint);
> }

Call made from tenant 1 App1 should always hit tenant 1 App 2 as each tenants app urls are unique. This does not happen all the time, but a few times a day.
Sufficient logging has been added

Comment: Is there a log when this happens? And could you share some key information.

Comment: When App 2 receives any call from App 1, it verifies the tenant of App 1 before executing the request so as there are no cross requests among tenants. This is done by verifying a unique key for each tenant. The only logging we have are the tenant ids of App 1 and App 2 and the exception being the tenant unique keys not matching. Other than this there are no exceptions logged by .netFx